# how can i Filter and escape all input data in mvc pattern?

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller

i am using my own mvc framework and i want to filter and escape all of the input and out put automatically. How do I?

Comment: This heavily depends on how you handle input/output in your application. Perhaps you can show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which filters the data as you want. Then at the very beginning you put this code:

```
array_map('your_filter_function', $_REQUEST);
```

Alternatively you can create a class which wraps the post and get super globals. If I want to get a post variable in Codeigniter, for example, I do this:

```
$post_var = $this->input->post('key');
```

And the function post could if you wanted to filter the value before it retrieves it (return your_filter_function($_POST['key']));

Escaping output would be done by adding this feature to your database layer, or other sources of output.